# How to fix "User.findOne()" returning null for user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently working on a new project and I'm trying to get the login route working. But the login always fails because the User.findOne() method is always returning as null.

I've tried changing the export from the usermodel to

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'User');
```

But it hasn't change anything.

I know the connection to the database is fine because the register route works fine and saves correctly.

Login Route

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password }, function (err, user) {
        if (err || user == null) {
            res.redirect('/login');
            console.log(user);
        } else {
            req.session.userId = user._id;
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});
```

User Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

UserSchema.statics.authenticate = function (email, password, callback) {
    User.findOne({ email: email }).exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        } else if (!user) {
            var err = new Error('User not found.');
            err.status = 401;
            return callback(err);
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function (err, result) {
            if (result === true) {
                return callback(null, user);
            } else {
                return callback();
            }
        });
    });
};

//hashing a password before saving it to the database
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var user = this;
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});

var User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Database Connection

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/wowDb', { useNewUrlParser: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () { });
```

I used

```
db.users.findOne({username: "Imortalshard"});
```

and got the output

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cc10cd13361880abc767d78"),
        "email" : "admin@wowdb.com",
        "username" : "Imortalshard",
        "password" : "$2b$10$7Ln5yHFqzPw/Xz6bAW84SOVhw7.c0A1mve7Y00tTdaKzxzTph5IWS",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

[Console output from console.log(req.body) and console.log(user)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ0OX.png)

I'm waiting the user that i registered to be able to successfully login, but currently it is just redirecting me back to the login page and giving me a null reading for user in the console.

Comment: If you tried changing that line then you clearly read an existing answer. But what you are probably missing is what is the actual collection in the database you are connecting to named? That third agument is meant to reflect the actual collection name. Without that argument, mongoose is expecting a collection named `users` based on `'User'` as the declared name for the model. Unless you use `db.User.find()` in the `mongo` shell to return results, then that's probably still the wrong collection name.  It's probably `db.user.find()`, and therefore `mongoose.model('User', UserShema, 'user')`

Comment: Either that, or the named database on the URI passed to `mongoose.connect()` is different from where you actually stored the data. Entering the `mongo` shell or Compass for example connects to the `test` database by default. No result only ever means only one of **four** things. 1. Nothing matches the query predicate given. 2. Pointing to the wrong collection name. 3. Pointing to the wrong database name. 4. Simply connecting to a different MongoDB instance than where the data is stored.

Comment: @NeilLunn db.users.findOne({username : <the username>}); works fine in the mongo shell as i checked to make sure the saving was correct from the register form. I've double checked the database name for the mongoose.connect and it is correct as well.

Comment: Instead of double checking, include the code that actually shows the connection string and the steps you used from the mongo shell to verify what you want to retrieve exists in your question. Then we can all "double check" with you. I also notice you have `email` and `password` on the `findOne()` request. From the other code the `password` would appear to be hashed and therefore not likely what you are sending in from `req.body`. Show those values in your question too, along with the document you expect to match and can match from the mongo shell.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've made the edits you requested. The image shows the output from both console.log(req.body) and console.log(user).